# Family Tree Maker 2005 files import to 2019 version?

Tags: gedcom, family-tree-maker

I have Family Tree Maker 2005.  Yeah, I know...way outta date.  But when Ancestry said they weren't going to support it anymore, I just kept what I had.  It works fine.  Now I want to upgrade (actually have to purchase a new version).  I'm looking at Family Tree Maker 2019 and it's now made by MacKiev.

Will my .ftm files open up in the new program?  Will the Gedcom files I export from my old version open up in the 2019 version?  Can I IMPORT my files to the new version?

The thought of manually entering all this information again is disheartening.  Tell me something good, people.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to upgrade your old FTM to the new version. The best thing for you to do right now is to purchase FTM17, since MacKiev is giving a free FTM19 upgrade to customers who are purchasing FTM17 right now and you can upload your old .FTM file to your new FTM software. Please [click here](https://familytreemakersupport.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-old-ftm/) to read the blog. The blog has a step by step guide to get your old file imported in your new Family Tree Maker software.

Answer (score 0):

Family Tree Maker 2019 has an import/export function in the "File menu" in the task bar. It took hours until I went in to the search bar and found a way to export. Everybody I spoke with told me to upgrade but I was worried I would lose all my data.

I asked a computer expert at Family Tree Maker, and nobody told me to check in the File menu and that I would be able to import files from 2005 version to the 2019 version. My mistake was I did not create a name for my file; otherwise I would have been able to do it in one shot instead of one at a time.